# Background and overlay picture (blur effect) risize different, how can i fix this?

Tags: resize, background-image, blurry

So guys, recently i've been working to figure out how to get a frostet glass effect SOMEWHERE on my Background Image. as is turned out it's not that easy, but i think i'm very Close!
it works pretty good so far as Long as you use your browser in Fullscreen. Even if you resize the width of your Browsers window it still works just fine. but if you change the height it gets annoying, because the frostet glass part shrinks faster than the actual Background Image, and i do not know how to fix it. any suggestions?

thanks a lot!

### here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>


<head>
    <link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>


<body>
        <p id="test" class="glass down"> test</p>
</body>


</html>
```

### here is my CSS:

```
html, body, .glass {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}


body {
    background-image: url('../images/slide/slide2.JPG');
    background-size: cover;
}


.glass::before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:112.5%;  /*diese beiden prozente beschreiben meine lage im vollbild*/
    left:-50%;
    width: 199%; /*diese beiden prozente beschreiben meine größe*/
    height:199%;
    background-image: url('../images/slide/slide2.jpg');
    filter: blur(5px);
    background-size: cover;
    content: ' ';
    opacity: 0.6;
}


.glass {
    background-color: white;
}


.glass.down {
    transform: translateY(100%) translateY(-7rem);
}


.glass.down::before {
    transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(7rem);
}


.glass.up, .glass.up::before {
    transform: translateY(0%);
}


#test { 
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 50%; /*ändert die größe meines ausschnittes */
height: 50%;
z-index: 10000;
}
```

I hope you can help me somehow. thanks again :)